# How to keep track of all nodes in a linkedlist using only one variable?

Tags: c, linked-list, printf, nodes, stdin

The program will read values that are typed in by the user iteratively in a while loop. Every time the value is read, a new node will be created with this integer value. Now I'll make a LinkedList using these created nodes. And then print out every value stored in the LinkedList. I expect the order of reading in and the order of printing out are reversed. The following is my main function where readline is just a function that prints a message and reads an input, make_new_node is a function that takes in a value and makes a new node with this value, printlink is the function that prints out all the values saved in every node in the linked list, and freelink contains the free function. For now, I only get a printed-out result of the last integer typed in. With just one node variable n, how can I possibly print out all the value members of every node in the linked list?

```
int main()
{
    char buf[100];
    int num;
    Node* n = NULL;

    while(1) {
        readline("The num to put in?: ", buf, sizeof(buf));
        sscanf(buf, "%d", &num);
        if(num == -1) {
            n -> next = NULL;
            printlink(n);
            freelink(n);    
            break;      
        } else {
            n = make_new_node(num);
            n -> next = n;      
        }               
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if the First entry is -1? Looks like a GPF

Comment: It would need to be a doubly linked list (both forward and back) for you to be able to go back after making the list and not storing the head.

Comment: You need to save the old value of `n` before you do `n = make_new_node(num);`. `n -> next = n;` is just pointing the next back to itself.

Comment: Why do you have a restriction saying there must only be **one** node variable?

Comment: Just personally, I don't want to make another Node* unless I have to... Sorry if that causes any ambiguity.

Comment: Well, the simple solution to your problem requires one more variable. That is also what is done in the answer you accepted. So the question title becomes kind of misleading. The correct answer to this question would be "Given the functions you have available, it is not possible to build the list using just **one** node variable".

Comment: Maybe I should change the title question to "Can I keep track of all nodes in a linkedlist using only one variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would generally approach this, but I guess it breaks your rule about using only a single node pointer?  Is that a limitation specified in how you are allowed to solve the problem, or just a limitation you ran into based on your implementation?

```
int main()
{
    char buf[100];
    int num;
    Node *head = NULL, *n;
    while(1){
        readline("The num to put in?: ", buf, sizeof(buf));
        sscanf(buf, "%d", &num);
        if (num == -1){
            printlink(n);
            freelink(n);    
            break;      
        } else{
            n = make_new_node(num);
            n -> next = head;
            head = n;     
        }               
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store a reference to the first node. Since you never add any nodes before this one you could just have a method that takes the first node and iterates through your list via next.

Alternatively you could make a doubly linked list where you have a next AND a previous variable. Your method could then find the first node by going back via previous.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way is to change the signature of `make_new_node` to

```
Node * make_new_node(int new_value, Node *current_head);
```

Code then become:

```
    } else {
        n = make_new_node(num, n);
    }
```

A classical stack implementation is for example

```
Node * make_new_node(int new_value, Node *current_head) {
    Node *n = malloc(*Node);
    n->value = new_value;
    n-> next = current_head;
    return n;
}
```

But in that case, this

```
    if(num == -1) {
        n -> next = NULL; // NO!
```

would immediately trunk the (stack) linked list to only one element, all other would be leaked...